# How to inject repository pattern to event Laravel

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection

I use repository patter. If I want use repistory in my controller(for example UserRepository) I simple inject repository in my controller

```
class SomeController extend BaseController
     public function __contruct(UserRepositoryInterface $user){
          $this->user = $user;
     }
```

In this example laravel automaticlly inject repository to my controller. But now I would like make some operation on my database from event. So I would like inject UserRepository to my event. How can I do it?

```
 class UserHandlerEvent {
     public function onCreate($event){}
     public function subscribe($events){
         $event->listen('user.create', 'UserHandlerEvent@onCreate');
 }
```

This is my event, next I regiter it in my EventServiceProvider. It is looks like

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(){
        $this->app->events->subscribe(new UserEventHandler());
    }
}
```

What should I do, if I want have to access to UserRepository from my event?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constructor in your UserHandlerEvent class and inject the UserRepositoryInterface as you did in your controller.

```
class UserHandlerEvent {
 protected $user;
 public function __contruct(UserRepositoryInterface $user){
          $this->user = $user;
     }
     public function onCreate($event){}
     public function subscribe($events){
         $event->listen('user.create', 'UserHandlerEvent@onCreate');
 }
```

Comment: What with my EventServiceProvider? I would have to pass some variable to UserHandlerEvent

Comment: I think the IOC container will instantiate the UserRepository on its own. You don't have to pass the any variable, just give it a try.